# char* - why is there no address in the pointer?

Tags: c++

I have a basic question about `char*` I don't understand

```
char* aString = "Hello Stackoverflow";
```

The Pointer points at the first character of the character chain.

```
cout << *aString; // H
```

but why is the whole string saved in the pointer?

```
cout << aString //Hello Stackoverflow
```

I would expect an address, aren't addresses saved in pointers? Where is the address of "Hello Stackoverflow"?

Any help much appreciated

Comment: I know it's just an example, but anyway, assigning string literals to non-const pointers is poor practice.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is an overload for `operator<<(ostream&, char const*)` which output the null-terminated string starting at that pointer and which is preferred to the operator `ostream::operator<<(void*)` which would have output the address.

If you want the address, cast the pointer to `void*`.

Answer (score 8):

The string is saved sequentially, starting from that position. The rules of C, inherited by C++ simply state that when you try to use a `char *` as a string, it will keep reading characters until encountering a 0 **byte**.

If you **do** want to get an address, tell `cout` to not interpret it as a "string":

```
std::cout << (void *)aString << std::endl;
```

---

#### EDIT

> Where does the standard state that 0 == '\0'?

From a C++11 draft, section 2.3-3:

> The basic execution character set and the basic execution wide-character set shall each contain all the members of the basic source character set, plus control characters representing alert, backspace, and carriage return, **plus a null character (respectively, null wide character), whose representation has all zero bits**.

Comment: @David It's the same thing :-) `0 == '\0'`

Comment: 0 is the same value as '\0'.

Comment: Oh, well I thought if I put in a 0 in the middle of the string, it would stop at that point...Simple misconception on my part.

Comment: @David That's what I'm saying, it will stop at any 0 byte.

Comment: @David Thats's not a 0 byte, it's '0', which in ascii is **48**.

Comment: @David you are trying this, "abc0". Here it is `'0'` with ASCII 48. `\0` means ASCII 0.

Comment: @cnicutar That's what I'm trying to say. If I was a beginner reading your post, I would think that the string would stop when it sees the number 0 and not a 0 byte.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb, btw has `\0` the value `0` in ebcdic and unicode as well?

Comment: its value is independent of its encoding, last time i looked at the spec (but iirc for this one, it is guaranteed that all bits are zero).

Comment: Where does the standard state that `0 == '\0'`?

Comment: @cnicutar thanks, found it, this is a quote from a C++11 draft, section 2.3-3, add it if you want: _"The basic execution character set and the basic execution wide-character set shall each contain all the
members of the basic source character set, plus control characters representing alert, backspace, and carriage return, **plus a null character (respectively, null wide character), whose representation has all zero bits**."_

Answer (score 0):

`aString` does indeed hold an address, but the overload of `operator<<` that your code selects (`operator<<(ostream&, const char*)`) happens to print not the address that it is given, but the null terminated string starting at that address.

If you want to print the address, you can use the `ostream::operator<<(void*)` overload by casting `aString` to `void*`.