# Am I correctly understanding what all these pointers are pointing at?

Tags: c++

I created a program that creates three c-strings, then an array of pointers the size of the amount of c-strings that I created (3), with each pointer in the array pointing at the first character of each of the three strings, and then finally a pointer to the array of pointers (which would be pointing at the first pointer in the array).

Here's the code:

```
    int main() {
    char arr1 [] = "hello";
    char arr2 [] = "dear";
    char arr3 [] = "world";

    char* p1[3];
    *p1 = arr1;
    *(p1+1) = arr2;
    *(p1+2) = arr3;
    char** ptr = p1;
}
```

However, when I do something like `std::cout << *ptr << std::endl;` I expect it to just output the ADDRESS of the first pointer in the array of pointers. However, it actually prints out the whole word `"hello"`, which seems weird to me. I would expect an address, and if I outputted `**ptr`, I would expect for it to just print out the letter `"h"` (which it actually does)Am I not understanding something correctly? The same thing if I did `std::cout << *(ptr+1)`..I would expect the address of the second pointer in the array of pointers `p1`, but it actually prints out the whole word "dear." I'm so lost..I thought dereferencing `ptr` would give me the address to `p1`, which dereferencing it twice would give me the value inside of the address of `p1`.

Comment: Hint: What *type* of pointer does `*ptr` evaluate to, and is there an operator for the output stream that deals with those? What happens if you cast to `void*` instead? Is the outcome something different?

Comment: `dereferencing` gives you the object the pointer is pointing to. If you did `cout << *(&ptr))`, this should give the address I believe

Comment: @WhozCraig *ptr evaluates to a char pointer, right? and we've never done anything like "void*" in my class so I have no clue what that is ahh.  (lol I keep tying the deferencing symbol on here and it deletes it for some reason *"

Comment: It *does* eval to a `char *`, you're correct. And as you've discovered, there is a `ostream` operator override for `<<` that takes `const char*` on the right side. It dumps *the string*; not the pointer. So to step around that you need to change the type to something `ostream` will dump by *value* rather than dereference (such as `const void*`). Try it: `std::cout << static_cast<const void*>(*ptr) << std::endl;`

Comment: improve representation when you post a question it counts

Comment: @WhozCraig okay, so that's just an automatic thing that the ostream does when it's dealing with c-strings?

Comment: I suggest reading a good book about C because all those answers will hook you up.

Comment: @adripanico we're doing C++ in my class (and the only other language I've ever looked at was Java). I can barely keep up as it is haha, I don't think I could start reading another book

Comment: Seriosly. It's very important some draws to represent how pointers works and to understand it. Other way you will be crazy when you start  passing triple or quad pointers to a function for allocating memory. Also, starting with Java don't help at all :P Good luck!

Comment: @adripanico I'll look into it! Also, do you know why people are deleting their own answers? I had 3 other people post answers but they have since deleted their answers, I am not sure why.

Comment: because they think they can remember all about pointers but then they realised they were wrong :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanna print out the pointer, you should cast it to void pointer:

```
cout << (const void*) *ptr << endl;
```

because char * is actually old style C string, and there is an overloaded function:

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, const char *);
```

that output the string instead of pointer address. For other pointers, it should just work fine.

Comment: You meant `void` not `voif`?

Answer (score 3):

The "abnormalities" you see have nothing to do with pointers but with `<< operator`.

```
std::cout << *ptr << std::endl;
```

is equivalent to

```
std::cout << arr1 << std::endl;
```

Thus overloaded << operator:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const char* s);
```

is called. `arr1` decays to `const char* s`. `s` is a treated as C string and printed until '\0'

Answer (score 1):

Might be related aswell: [char* - Why is there no address in the pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551511/char-why-is-there-no-address-in-the-pointer?rq=1)

As people have said the problem you're having is that you're hitting the

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const char* str);
```

output operator which will print the c-string out for you, if you cast it to `void*` it will instead print the address just as you expected. As far as i can tell you've understood it correctly. One way you can think of pointers to pointers are arrays of arrays, with that thought in mind your example could be rewritten to something like this (this is not totally equivalent though):

```
int main() {
char arr1 [] = "hello";
char arr2 [] = "dear";
char arr3 [] = "world";

char p1[3][10];
p1[0] = arr1; //or *(p1+1) = arr1
p1[1] = arr2; //or *(p1+2) = arr2
p1[2] = arr3; //or *(p1+3) = arr3
char** ptr = p1;
}
```

I chose 10 just to be able to fit in the longest of the strings and a few extra chars. This would look something like this in memory:

```
hello\0----dear\0-----world\0----
^          ^          ^
|          |          |
|          |          arr3,ptr[2]
|          arr2,ptr[1]
*ptr/ptr[0], arr1
```

Where the dashes are just garbled data which can be anything because we chose the size 10 for our `char p1[3][10];`. Hopefully the image gives a little more info on how it looks and where the pointers go. Although, if we would have used `malloc()` to create this structure we could have done it in a few different ways, for example:

```
char* a = (char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
char* b = (char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
char* c = (char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
strcpy(a, "hello");
strcpy(b, "dear");
strcpy(c, "world");
char** ptrs = (char**)malloc(3*sizeof(char*)); //3 pointers, ie: char* ptr[3];
ptrs[0] = a;
ptrs[1] = b;
ptrs[2] = c;
```

This could look something like this:

```
ptrs:---|, --|, ------|
        v    v        v
        a-\  b-----\  c----\
          v        v       v
         "hello"  "dear"  "world"
```

Ie: They wouldn't be laid out as a long line anymore but each and every thing we've allocated would be in it's own place. So `ptrs` has pointers to a, b and c, while they in turn have pointers to the start of the strings "hello", "dear" and "world". So if we dereference `ptrs` (`*ptrs`) we'll get a pointer to `a` (a `char*` as we dereference a `char**`) which is a pointer to the first letter in "hello". When this is sent to `cout` it finds the forementioned `operator<<` for c-strings and therefore prints out the string it found. Something that's probably important to mention here is that `*ptrs` is equivalent to `ptrs[0]` but it would seem you've already grasped that.

And hopefully i haven't totally screwed this up by feeding you bogus information, if anyone sees something that's wrong or if i'm totally mistaken please do tell me so that i can remove this as others have done x) Also i hope this made it clearer in some way, please ask away if ther's anything that's unclear.